# Complicated reading from a file (Visual studio 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io

I'm stuck at reading data from a file. So here goes. I have etc. 5 chess games, but i have some figures lost, (1st file), however, some ppl bring me some figures of their own (2nd file) and i need to calculate how many complete chess tables I have in the end. Long story short. This is an example of the first file. All i need is to figure out how to read it properly. In the reading loop it is obvious that i will be getting the last line only, but this was my best shot. I dont know how to get all the data in the memory of class. Im new to this stuff, thanks for any help :

```
//5-number of incomplete chess games. P/Z/R/B/V/K-names of figures. 8/2/2/2/1/1-number of figures
//balta/juoda-white/black; if there is any other way to write this file in a different way and im too stupid to figure it out i would be thankful for the info

5 
1 P 8 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 8 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda
2 P 6 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 6 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda
3 P 4 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 4 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda
4 P 2 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 2 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda
5 P 0 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 0 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda



#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

    const int Cn = 100;

const char CFd1[] = "Komplektai.txt";
const char CFd2[] = "Parama.txt";
const char CFr[] = "Turnyras.txt";

class Komplektas
{
private:
    int eil;
    char fig;
    int kiek;
    string spal;
public:
    void Deti(int e, char f, int k, string s);
    int ImtiEile()  { return eil; }
    char ImtiFigura() { return fig; }
    int ImtiKieki() { return kiek; }
    string ImtiSpalva() { return spal; }
};

void Komplektas::Deti(int e, char f, int k, string s)
{
    eil = e;
    fig = f;
    kiek = k;
    spal = s;
}

void Skaityti1(string fv, Komplektas A[], int & x1, int & j);

void Spausdinti1(string fv, Komplektas A[], int x1, int j);

int main()
{
    int x1;
    int j;
    Komplektas A[Cn];
    Skaityti(CFd1, A, x1, j1);
    Spausdinti(CFr, A, x1, j1);


    cout << "Programa baige darba" << endl;
    return 0;
}

void Skaityti(string fv, Komplektas A[], int & x, int & j)
{
    int eil, kiek;
    char fig;
    string spal;
    ifstream fd(fv.c_str());
    fd >> x;
    fd >> j;
    for (int t = 0; t < x; t++)
        fd >> eil;
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
            fd >> fig >> kiek >> spal;
            A[i].Deti(eil, fig, kiek, spal);
            fd.ignore();
        }
        fd.close();
}
void Spausdinti(string fv, Komplektas A[], int x, int j)
{
    ofstream fr(fv.c_str());
    fr << x << endl;
    fr << j << endl;
    for (int t = 0; t < x; t++){
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
            fr << A[i].ImtiEile() << " " << A[i].ImtiFigura() << " " << A[i].ImtiKieki() << " " << A[i].ImtiSpalva() << endl;
        }
    }
        fr.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused, as I do not speak Lithuanian, however, as far as I can see, your read method (`Skaityti`) reads all the content and stores it in a one-dimensional array. You are looping all rows and you are storing all the values from `eil`. However, after you read the first row and get to the second row you overwrite the values of the first row and so on. When you reach the last row, you are reading it and overwrite the penultimate row. I believe the solution would be to have a two-dimensional array, the first dimension representing the rows and the second dimension would represent the values of the given row. This way you would have the values for each row.

So if `A` is an array of `Komplektas` arrays, like

`Komplektas A[r][v]`, where `r` represents the number of rows and `v` represents the number of values, then you could store the `t`th row's `i`th value into `A[t][i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and sorry for the language in the code. Still amazed you knew what language is it. I tried to do something with two dimensional arrays (matrix), but im completely green in such stuff. Heres my try. Thats what im getting:

```
1 P 0 balta 1 Z 0 balta 1 R 0 balta 1 B 0 balta 1 V 0 balta 1 K 0 balta 1 P 0 juoda 1 Z 0 juoda 1 R 0 juoda 1 B 0 juoda 1 V 0 juoda 1 K 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 
1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 
1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 
1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 
1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda 1 2 0 juoda
```

instead of :

```
5 13
1 P 8 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 8 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda
2 P 6 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 6 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda
3 P 4 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 4 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda
4 P 2 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 2 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda
5 P 0 balta Z 2 balta R 2 balta B 2 balta V 1 balta K 1 balta P 0 juoda Z 2 juoda R 2 juoda B 2 juoda V 1 juoda K 1 juoda



class Komplektas
{
private:
    int eil;
    char fig;
    int kiek;
    string spal;
public:
    Komplektas(int e = 0, char f = 0, int k = 0, string s = "") :
        eil(e), fig(f), kiek(k), spal(s) { }
    ~Komplektas() { }
    void Deti(int e, char f, int k, string s) { eil = e; fig = f, spal = s; }
    int ImtiEile()  { return eil; }
    char ImtiFigura() { return fig; }
    int ImtiKieki() { return kiek; }
    string ImtiSpalva() { return spal; }
};


class Matrica
{
public:
    static const int CMaxEil = 100;
    static const int CMaxSt = 15;
private:
    Komplektas A[CMaxEil][CMaxSt];
    int n;
    int m;
public:
    Matrica(int nn = 0, int mm = 0) : n(nn), m(mm) { }
    ~Matrica()                                     { }
    int ImtiN() { return n; }
    int ImtiM() { return m; }
    void DetiN(int nn) {n = nn;}
    void DetiM(int mm) {m = mm;}
    void DetiReiksme(int i, int j, Komplektas r) { A[i][j] = r; }
    Komplektas ImtiReiksme (int i, int j) { return A[i][j]; }
};

void Skaityti1(string fv, Matrica & A);
void Spausdinti1(string fv, Matrica & A);

int main()
{
    Matrica figuros;
    Skaityti1(CFd1, figuros);
    Spausdinti1(CFr, figuros);

    cout << "Programa baige darba" << endl;
    return 0;
}

void Skaityti1(string fv, Matrica & A)
{
    int n, m, eil, kiek;
    char fig;
    string spal;
    Komplektas x;
    ifstream fd(fv);
    fd >> n >> m;
    A.DetiN(n);
    A.DetiM(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fd >> eil;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            fd >> fig >> kiek >> spal;
            x.Deti(eil, fig, kiek, spal);
            A.DetiReiksme(i, j, x);
            cout << x.ImtiEile() << " " << x.ImtiFigura() << " " << x.ImtiKieki() << " " << x.ImtiSpalva() << endl;
        }
        }
        fd.close();
    }

void Spausdinti1(string fv, Matrica & A)
{
    Komplektas x;
    ofstream fr(fv);
    cout << A.ImtiN() << " " << A.ImtiM() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.ImtiN(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.ImtiM(); j++) {
            x = A.ImtiReiksme(i, j);
            fr << x.ImtiEile() << " " << x.ImtiFigura() << " " <<
x.ImtiKieki() << " " << x.ImtiSpalva() << " ";
        }
    fr << endl;
    }
    fr.close();
}
```